# Issue with Session and Cookie in Internet Explorer for websites containing underscore

Tags: internet-explorer, session, cookies, session-cookies

Recently we have created few websites with underscore (contains under website name).
 -------->  example (xyz_mnp.com)

Issue is: Every time a page request cookie and session resets.
It works fine with other browser but facing issue in IE

I search lots of thread but didn't find any solution yet.

Any help guys.
Thanks

Comment: The underscore in website name should not effect cookies. Cookie is set in in domain level. How do you know it resets the cookie in IE?

Comment: There are lot of threads which suggest and my personal experience
IE ignores cookies with domain containing underscores

Answer (score 16):

Internet Explorer rejects all cookies with an underscore in the domain, because underscores are not allowed in DNS hostnames. This is a well-known limitation in IE, documented in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/08/20/wininet-ie-cookie-internals-faq.aspx

The workaround is to remove the underscore from the hostname.