# PHP session variables issue with IE only

Tags: php, session, iis

I have got an issue which I am 99% sure is related to Internet Explorer (no way!): session variables are not being carried from one file to another (on the same domain). The pages are served by IIS 7.

To simplify the problem-solving process I have created two test files:

**test_1.php:**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] = '123';
?>
<a href="test_2.php">Go to result</a>
```

**test_2.php:**

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['test'];
session_unset();
?>
<a href="test_1.php">Go to page 1</a>
```

This works as expected in Chrome 33.0.1750.154 and Firefox 28.0, but in IE9 I get the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: test in D:\test_2.php on line 3
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks

Comment: Is your copy of IE blocking cookies?

Comment: make sure `session_id()` returns the SAME value in both scripts. If you get different values, then your session cookies are set incorrectly and you're getting a different session in each script.

Comment: cfr John Conde, a different browser settings (for cookies, security,...) is the only plausible explanation for this. When facing a client problem (difference depending on browser), always look in the client part. What's the client part of sessions ? cookies (most of the time)

Comment: The IDs are different (in IE only!), so that's a start. We are on a network and all computers (that we've tested) seem to be affected, so it may well be a cookie setting that needs setting globally. Do you have any idea what this might be? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally realised this issue was **due to there being an underscore in the IIS virtual directory/application**, with help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21032779/1358231/).