# Laravel 5, Forms, TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 46

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I keep getting the "TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 46" error when submitting forms.

This is one of the forms:

```
{!! Form::model($product, array('url' => 'product/'.$product->id, 'class' => 'form', 'method' => 'PATCH')) !!}

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::textarea('note', $product->note,
        array('class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>'product-note', 'placeholder'=>Lang::get('customtranslation.form_placeholder_note'), 'rows'=>3)) !!}
    <br />
    <span class="btn btn-link" id="remove-note" role="button"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> {{ Lang::get('customtranslation.button_txt_reset_note') }}</span>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::submit(Lang::get('customtranslation.button_txt_finish_edit_product'), array('class'=>'btn btn-success')) !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <!-- Custom tags -->
    {!! Form::label('additional-tags', Lang::get('customtranslation.form_edit_label_additional_tags')) !!}
    {!! Form::text('additional-tags','', array('id'=>'additional-tags', 'data-role'=>'tagsinput')) !!}
</div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

The input element with name "_token" gets generated and set as expected.

The strange thing is that this occurs only in Internet Explorer (IE11). Chrome and FF make a submit without any problems.

Does anyone else have this problem and a possible solution?

Comment: Debug your application and make sure that you are getting _token parameter in your request.

Comment: show us code of that form

Comment: Thank you all for your reply. I have updated my question with the code that generates the form. The problem occurs only in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Is it possible that your domain name has an underscore in it? like http://local_host/

Comment: @Chris It has an underscore in it. I have changed the underscore to hyphen and now everything works ok. Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: I will chuck it as an answer if you would like to accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internet explorer rejects sessions from domains with an underscore it. This is a known issue.

Please see here: [Issue with Session and Cookie in Internet Explorer for websites containing underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012559/issue-with-session-and-cookie-in-internet-explorer-for-websites-containing-under)

And also:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/08/20/wininet-ie-cookie-internals-faq.aspx

Comment: I have this problem in chrome too in FF forms work fine, any solution?

Comment: @Adamnick This is a very common problem (Token Mismatch) usually stemming from a misunderstanding of what the token is trying to do. Usually the above answer is not the solution (this one only covers the IE issue). If you are having a token mismatch issue, I would suggest asking your own question and link me to it so I can have a look

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have not set the `_token` parameter in your request to the server or you have put it in somewhere incorrect.

Comment: The _token gets generated automaticaly by Laravel.